# Is there any way to filter the data to view only county level data?

Tags: data.gov

This is for data.gov and thanks for answering the question.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the use you intend for the data? and what do you want to get out of the country level filtering - web pages or links to datasets or ...?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to clarify your question to be more specific. But, if I understand correctly, you can filter by Organization Type and select "county government" on the left side of the page.  https://catalog.data.gov/dataset#sec-organization_type

[image]